# Mysql child with multiple parents of same type

Tags: mysql, join, parent

I have recipes in mysql database (for website) that I will need to attach to other recipes as a parent child relationship. I need one recipe to be able to have multiple parent recipes. Initially I thought I could have a parent_id column in the recipes table, but if a recipe has multiple parents that doesn't work. I then thought I would just need to make a look up table where parent_id and child_id match up, but both the parent and child are recipes, so how would the query know to differentiate which is parent and which is the child when I do the select statement? Does this make sense??

Comment: Nothing you mentioned scares me from a schema point of view.  Can you describe the sort of queries you plan on running?

Comment: So recipes have multiple parents and multiple children?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on the entire scope as I'll have to figure this part out first and then build one piece at a time; but the next step will be to list all the recipes I suppose in an indented fashion - array('Chicken Salad')

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on the entire scope as I'll have to figure this part out first and then build one piece at a time; but the next step will be to list all the recipes I suppose in an indented fashion - 
array(
'Chicken Salad' =>'Aunt Jeans Special Dressing',
'Taco Salad' =>'Aunt Jeans Special Dressing',
);
getAllRecipes(){
$sql = SELECT * FROM `recipes`;
}
getChildRecipes($parent_id){
$sql = SELECT * FROM `recipes` WHERE parent_id = $parent_id;
}

Comment: and then merge them together maybe in php or something to achieve this kind of result

Chicken Salad
    Aunt Jeans Special Dressing
        Garlic Lemon Puree sauce
Taco Salad
    Aunt Jeans Special Dressing

Comment: Strawberry, Yes exactly. What's confusing me is that they are all in the same table 8\ if it was like a product in multiple different categories (parents) like electronic, housewares etc I could figure that out; but a recipe has multiple recipe parents and children which are all recipes. 8(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a tow tables: `recipes(ID, ...)` and `connections(pID, cID)`

Every recipe have a `ID` and inside `connections` you save a parent-child connections.

`recipes` will look like this

```
(0, Soup)
(1, Cookie)
(2, Cookiesoup)
```

`connections` will look like this

```
(0, 2)
(1, 2)
```

To query all child recipes of `Soup` with `ID` = 0 you can use this

```
SELECT * FROM recipes JOIN connections ON recipes.ID = connections.cID WHERE connections.pID = 0
```

To query all parents recipes of `Cookiesoup` with `ID` = 2 you can use this

```
SELECT * FROM recipes JOIN connections ON recipes.ID = connections.pID WHERE connections.cID = 2
```

Comment: @marcus I have the same scenario, but it goes deeper than one level. I wonder, how to query all parents/children with recursion?